# How to recognize when user stop speaking by HTML 5 Audio?

Tags: html, html5-audio, audio-recording, recorder.js

Here is the thing: I am using recorderJS to record Audio from user microphone.
And I need to trigger an event each time user stop speaking mean no input sounds to the microphone.
Is there are any idea how to do it?